# How to create a shared parameter that can be shared when project standards are transferred

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I am working on a project where I need to create multiple revit files consisting of wall types and create shared parameters into them. I completed this process.

But on manually clicking on 
Manage > Transfer Project Standards 

Copy from "project name" > Wall Types through the revit interface.

I imported the wall types of different revit files created into one.
But the shared parameters seems to repeat in the type parameter list of the wall type with data in one set and the repeated set has no data.

It looks like the parameters I created are not shareable.

```
if (Convert.ToString(value) != "")
            {
                Type type = value.GetType();
                string originalFile = uiApp.Application.SharedParametersFilename;
                string tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName()) + ".txt";
                using (File.Create(tempFile)) { }
                uiApp.Application.SharedParametersFilename = tempFile;
                try
                {
                    if (ele.LookupParameter(param) == null)
                    {
                        ExternalDefinitionCreationOptions edco = null;
                        if (type.Name.Equals("Double"))
                            edco = new ExternalDefinitionCreationOptions(param, ParameterType.Number);
                        else
                            edco = new ExternalDefinitionCreationOptions(param, ParameterType.Text);
                        edco.Visible = true;
                        var definition = uiApp.Application.OpenSharedParameterFile().Groups.Create("Custom Parameters").Definitions.Create(edco);
                        var newCategorySet = uiApp.Application.Create.NewCategorySet();
                        newCategorySet.Insert(doc.Settings.Categories.get_Item(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls));
                        Autodesk.Revit.DB.Binding binding = uiApp.Application.Create.NewTypeBinding(newCategorySet);
                        doc.ParameterBindings.Insert(definition, binding, BuiltInParameterGroup.PG_IDENTITY_DATA);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value))
                            ele.LookupParameter(param).Set((string)value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value))
                            ele.LookupParameter(param).Set((string)
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    uiApp.Application.SharedParametersFilename = originalFile;
                }
            }
```

Here, this block of code is executed in a loop where "element" is the element into whom the shared parameter needs to be added. "param" is the parameter name and "value" is the value for the parameter. 
 Please let me know if this is the right way to create shared parameter that can be shared when project wall types are transferred to another project.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

definitely this will happen, as long as you are in a loop, and keeps creating a shared parameter for each file. this will lead to creating unique GUID for each revit file. and when you combine all you will find all the shared parameters with different Guids but with the same name.

you need to create the shared parameter once, then for each revit file, set the sharedparameter file (that is already created with sharedparameter) and get the sharedparameter from it, then assign it to the category you wish for each revit file.

moreinfo about shared parameters [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Revit-API/files/GUID-C6FAC918-DC11-41B6-94FD-F745C3C00D98-htm.html)

hope that helps.